# How to enable “open in…” feature to html file attachment in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to enable "Open in..." feature to `.html` file attachment send through email.

I have modified `Info.plist` file as below, for `.odt` file attachment it is working fine.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>XDXF Document</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.mouritech.odt</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>html - XML Dictionary eXchange Format</string>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.mouritech.odt</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>odt</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>text/html</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

When I replace `odt` with `html`, it is not showing "Open in..." feature, by default it is opening.

Comment: Not sure, but isn't the Uniform Type Identifier for .html files already declared as public.html? So your application should just add support for that type identifier rather than specifying a new type identifier?

Comment: I changed UTTypeConformsTo public.html still not working...

Comment: No, you're declaring a new type you _export_ instead of declaring which types your application can _import_. `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` is what you want. Or just add `public.html` to your array of `LSItemContentTypes`.

Comment: i added public.html in LSItemContentTypes but still not working

Comment: Might your issue be similar to the one I'm having? See my current question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19000018/751061
Try testing your app from a different application's "open in..." dialog. For example the `DocInteraction` app by Apple. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)